# Probability of X or Y happening

Tags: probability

I was trying to work this out last night and it was driving me mad, as I've forgotten how to calculate the probability of X or Y happening. I am on an on-call rota at work, and we get around 3 callouts in a week. So, that means the chances of getting a callout on any given night are 3/7. If I want to know the chances of getting a callout on either a Monday or a Tuesday night, how would I approach that please?
Thanks
Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M = \text{callout on Monday}$ and $T = \text{callout on Tuesday}$. We know that
$$
P(M) = P(T) = \frac{3}{7}
$$
How would we combine them with an "or" operator? Well, if you draw the Venn diagram, you will see that
$$
P(M~\text{or}~T) = P(M)+P(T)- P(M~\text{and}~T)
$$
Since the two events are independent, we get $P(M~\text{and}~T)=P(M)P(T)$. Can you finish the calculation now?

---

Note that there are several ways of mathematically modeling this. Here, we assumed that the events are independent, and it could be that this is not exactly true. The sentence "we get around 3 callouts in a week, so (...) the chances of getting a callout on any given night are 3/7" is not entirely true. Why? Consider that you got a callout on Monday and Tuesday. Is the probability of a callout on Wednesday still 3/7? How about Thursday? As you see, there are several ways of going about this ...

Comment: Hi

Thanks for the response, so let me see if I follow the equation `P(M or T)=P(M)+P(T)−P(M and T)`

P(M)+P(T) is 3/7 + 3/7 = 6/7 (or 42/49 if you want the same denominator)

P(M and T) is 3/7 * 3/7 = 9/49

Which means that

P(M or T) = 42/49 - 9/49 = 33/49

Is that right?

Comment: Yes, with the given assumptions, that is correct.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!